# Why does lldb debugger assign a value when i set a watchpoint?

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

In the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned i = 1;
    while (i)
    {
        i <<= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I first compile with debugging info as followed: `gcc -g single-step.c`
Then I do `lldb a.out`. I want to see what i is doing, so i do `b main` and `run`, after which i set my watchpoint for i: `watchpoint set variable i`. When I do that however, lldb seems to assign a value to variable i, which it shouldn't 
`Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x16fdff498 size = 4 state = enabled type = w  declare @ '/Users/d1ff1cult/Documents/KUL 2021-2022/IW/oefenzitting-c/les8-debugging/examples/single-step.c:5' watchpoint spec = 'i' new value: 53472`  
It gives i a seemingly completely random value, so what am I doing wrong?
I use CLion to write my code, but this happens in the CLion terminal as well as my macOS proper terminal. I am also using an M1 Mac.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is probably displaying the value before `i` is initialized to `1` which is a separate operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eugene is correct.

On my system, when I run your program, I get an initial value of 0 at the watchpoint.

I changed the program to put your code in a function (e.g.) `orig`.

I created a function `fill` that loops on filling in its stack frame an int array of length 100.

From `main`, I call `fill` and then `orig` with `b orig`. Then, doing the watchpoint command, I get a value of 100.

So, your watchpoint is displaying *whatever* happens to be in the stack frame for what `i` is assigned to. That is, the *uninitialized* value.

Here is the test program I created:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
orig(void)
{
    unsigned i = 1;

    while (i) {
        i <<= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void
fill(void)
{
    unsigned x[100];

    for (int i = 0;  i < 100;  ++i)
        x[i] = rand();
}

int
main(void)
{

    fill();
    orig();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the debug output:

```
> lldb ./fix1
(lldb) target create "./fix1"
Current executable set to './fix1' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = fix1`main + 4 at fix1.c:29, address = 0x000000000040117b
(lldb) b orig
Breakpoint 2: where = fix1`orig + 4 at fix1.c:7, address = 0x000000000040112a
(lldb) run
Process 193289 launched: '/tmp/watch/fix1' (x86_64)
Process 193289 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'fix1', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000000040117b fix1`main at fix1.c:29
   26   main(void)
   27   {
   28   
-> 29       fill();
   30       orig();
   31   
   32       return 0;
(lldb) c
Process 193289 resuming
Process 193289 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'fix1', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x000000000040112a fix1`orig at fix1.c:7
   4    int
   5    orig(void)
   6    {
-> 7        unsigned i = 1;
   8    
   9        while (i) {
   10           i <<= 1;
(lldb) watchpoint set variable i
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0x7fffffffdd6c size = 4 state = enabled type = w
    declare @ '/tmp/watch/fix1.c:7'
    watchpoint spec = 'i'
    new value: 100
```

Comment: debug information doesn't generally represent variable initialization - that might be path dependent and would be hard to represent.  It tends to only track the lexical scope of the variables and their location in that scope.  Since the variable comes into scope when defined, and the debugger can't tell whether it's been initialized, it is going to report what is in that memory regardless of the initialization status of the value.